# Unable to read decompress classes.dex file ?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, apk

I have download an apk from the internet and decpress it using dex2jarf tool so its gives compiled,.classes files  which i convert into .java file through decompiler but it gives me classes toa proper way like it gives a.java,b.java c.java which is difficult to me read.Can i get proper classes name  through apk file same as it is used in project.plz help
Thanks

Comment: Probably depends on whether the original author has used proguard to obfuscate the code.

Comment: So how can get Actual classes.

Comment: I highly doubt it (but I don't know for sure). You know, it is exactly the aim to make reverse engineering as difficult as possible when using obfuscators.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is called **deobfuscation**.

Programmers who wish to protect their intellectual property obfuscate their code to make it more difficult to read for those who might want to steal/copy/plagiarise their hard work.

> Obfuscators replace these names with short, machine generated alternatives. Rather than seeing a call to dontAllow(), an attacker would see a call to a(). This makes it more difficult to intuit the purpose of these functions without access to the original source code.

Src: http://android-developers.blogspot.ie/2010/09/securing-android-lvl-applications.html

Comment: As computers can not identify the purpose of a method or class deobfuscation can not be performed automatically and requires human interaction.

Answer (score 0):

There is *no* way to recover identifiers if they have been stripped out. Compilation is a *lossy* process, like converting a `RAW` image to a low quality `JPEG`. There's no way to go from `JPEG` back to `RAW`.

However, there are tools like `jeb` and `ida` that allow you to rename the classes yourself. When renamed, all references to that class also get renamed. This feature is sometimes called "refactoring". This is about the best way to do it, but it takes more time.

Also, there are plugins for `jeb` that help automate the refactoring by generating new, more descriptive names than 'a', 'b', etc. Here's an example from jcase, which you can modify to suit your needs: https://github.com/CunningLogic/myJEBPlugins/blob/master/DeCluster.java